# Column Names on Feature Selection Output in Python (Scikit Learn)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, feature-selection

Disclaimer: I'm very new to Python.

I've done a preprocessing step of feature selection on my dataset in Python 2.7 scikit learn. In doing this, I've reduced the number of columns from 222 to 77.

My problem is the output of the feature selection is a numpy array, which appears to have stripped the column names. I need to know which columns were kept, but I'm not sure how to get this information if I can't see the column names.
Here's my feature selection code, which returns a matrix:

```
 clf = ExtraTreesClassifier()
 clf = clf.fit(X, y)
 clf.feature_importances_  
 model = SelectFromModel(clf, prefit=True)
 X_new = model.transform(X)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`model.get_support()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.get_support).

> **get_support(indices=False)**
>
> Get a mask, or integer index, of
>   the features selected

Lets say you have total 5 features in your X and 3 were selected from it: First, Second and fifth.

Then `model.get_support()` will return :

```
[True, True, False, False, True]
```

If you use `model.get_support(indices=True)`, then you will get:

```
[0,1,4]
```

Hope this clears your question.